# problem with building up react native app

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I want to create React Native app with Expo which will be able to read QR codes. I use 'react-native-qrcode-scanner', 'react-native-qrcode-scanner' and 'react-native-permissions' and also "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs" for navigation.
To create my app I have to build it first.
But every time I try "eas build --platform android" command I get an error with "Run gradlew":
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Umr9I.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GG0Jp.png)

I use "openjdk version "17.0.7" 2023-04-18", my Android Studio - Java v17.0.6
I have no idea how to fix it and I'm asking for your help.

I tried downgrading my JDK, also matching my package.json names with app.json app names, nothing helped me.